# Trace of six gamma matrices

Tags: mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras

I need to calculate this expression:
$$Tr(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma}\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{5}) $$ 
I know that I can express this as:
$$ Tr(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma}\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{5})=-4i(g^{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\alpha\beta}-g^{\mu\rho}\epsilon^{\nu\sigma\alpha\beta}+g^{\mu\sigma}\epsilon^{\nu\rho\alpha\beta}-g^{\mu\alpha}\epsilon^{\nu\rho\sigma\beta}+g^{\mu\beta}\epsilon^{\nu\rho\sigma\alpha}+g^{\nu\rho}\epsilon^{\mu\sigma\alpha\beta}-g^{\nu\sigma}\epsilon^{\mu\rho\alpha\beta}+g^{\nu\alpha}\epsilon^{\mu\rho\sigma\beta}-g^{\nu\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\rho\sigma\alpha}+g^{\rho\sigma}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}-g^{\rho\alpha}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\sigma\beta}+g^{\rho\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\sigma\alpha}+g^{\sigma\alpha}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\beta}-g^{\sigma\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\alpha}+g^{\alpha\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma})  $$
So, some of this terms are the same and some vanish. My question is how to show that.
I know that:
$$Tr(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma}\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{5})=-4i(g^{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\alpha\beta}-g^{\mu\rho}\epsilon^{\nu\sigma\alpha\beta}+g^{\rho\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\sigma\alpha\beta}-g^{\alpha\beta}\epsilon^{\sigma\mu\nu\rho}+g^{\sigma\beta}\epsilon^{\alpha\mu\nu\rho}-g^{\sigma\alpha}\epsilon^{\beta\mu\nu\rho}) $$
So only six terms survive, but how?

Comment: How do you know this should only have 6 terms? Is there a reference for that identity?

Comment: [Here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222621/trace-of-six-gamma-matrices) is the discussion on mathoverflow. Thanks for your interest in the problem.

Comment: Trace of a product of any odd number of Gamma matrices is 0. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Trace_identities for an outline of the proof.

Comment: @Archisman I fear you are misreading the rules: $\gamma_5$ counts as an *even* number, not an odd one. So the trace of an *even* number of games times $\gamma_5$  need not, and in fact does not vanish. See the valid answers in the math overflow site.

Comment: Per the linked wikipedia page: "Although $\gamma ^{5}$ uses the letter gamma, it is not one of the gamma matrices of $C\ell_{1,3}(\mathbf{R})$. The number 5 is a relic of old notation in which $\gamma ^{0}$ was called $\gamma^4$." So this is a trace of six gamma matrices, just as the OP's original title stated.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for correcting me.